# Dynamoose: No table has been registered

Tags: dynamodb-queries, dynamoose

I have a Dynamodb table that is being queried using Dynamoose but I am getting an error when the query is being run:

`` CustomError [OtherError]: No table has been registered for dev-production-history-table model. Use `new dynamoose.Table` to register a table for this model. ``

Here is the first part of the code:

````
    "id": String,
    "medicationCode": String,
    "createdYear": { hashKey: true, type: String },
    "createdDateComposite": { rangeKey: true, type: String },
    "createdDateTime": String,
    "serviceUserId": String,
    "createdBy": String,
    "updatedBy": String,
    "startDate": String,
    "numberOfDaysToProduce": Number,
    "recurrence": String,
    "additionalInfo": String,
    "days": String,
    "recurrenceValue": String,
    "status": String
}, {
    saveUnknown: true,
    timestamps: true,
}, );


const model = dynamoose.model<ProductionHistory>(DatabaseTableNames.productionHistoryTable,
    schema);```

Could someone please explain how I register the table for the model as I am finding it hard to find any documentation with an example?

Thanks.
````

Comment: Sounds like you are using v3 beta. You can find the v3 beta documentation at https://dynamoose.pages.dev/

Comment: Yes, that's right, but I cannot find how to register the table for the model within the documentation. There doesn't seem to be an example of that.

Comment: https://dynamoose.pages.dev/guide/Table#new-dynamoosetablename-models. Just creating a new table should do that.

Comment: Thanks. I have declared the table as a constant, but not actually used it anywhere and all seems to be working - very confusing! Thanks for your help.

Comment: I’d love to chat more about this to come up with better ways to handle this and make it less confusing. If you’d like, feel free to join the Dynamoose Slack channel (link in the repo README) and direct message me there, or contact me using the link in my Stack Overflow profile. No pressure to do so, but would be greatly appreciated if you could to gather more feedback to make improvements. Glad you were able to get it resolved! Happy coding.